# How to count identical 1kb blocks( in C)?

Tags: c

I am trying to count every 1kb content block of 2 files and I also want to compare these 1kb blocks of content and count the identical ones .
A smaller example of what I want to do would be:

```
file1:
"
Over hill, over dale,
Thorough bush, thorough brier,
Over park, over pale,
"
```

```
file3:
"
Over hill, over dale,
Thorough bush, thorough brier,
Over park, over pale,
"
```

these are smaller blocks, but what I want to print at the end is:

```
file1: 1( block of content)
file3: 1( block of content)
identical blocks:1
```

if file3 doesn't have any matching blocks(1kb) with file1 then this would be the output:

```
file1: 1( block of content)
file2: 1( block of content)
identical blocks:0
```

This is what I have written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


void compare(FILE *fp1, FILE *fp2)
{
char block1[1024];
char block2[1024];
int count_b_file1=0;
int count_b_file2=0;
int count_id=0;

for (;;)
{
size_t read_file=fread(block1,1,sizeof(block1),fp1);
if (read_file == 0){ break;}
count_b_file1=count_b_file1+1;
}

for (;;)
{

size_t read_file2=fread(block2,1,sizeof(block2),fp2);
if (read_file2 == 0){ break;}
count_b_file2=count_b_file2+1;

}

fseek(fp1,0,SEEK_SET);
fseek(fp2,0,SEEK_SET);


for (;;)
{
size_t read_file1=fread(block2,1,sizeof(block1),fp1);
if (read_file1==0)
{
break;
}
size_t read_file2=fread(block2,1,sizeof(block2),fp2);
if (read_file2==0)
{
break;
}
if ( memcmp (block1,block2,sizeof(block1))==0)
{
count_id=count_id+1;
}
}

printf("%d \n",count_b_file1);
printf("%d \n",count_b_file2);
printf("%d \n",count_id);


}

int main()
{
FILE *file1=fopen("file1","r");
FILE *file2=fopen("file3","r");


compare(file1,file2);

 fclose(file1);
 fclose(file2);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does it mean to "count all 1 kB blocks"? Is that the same or different than just taking the size of the file in units of 1 kB? Or do you want to count the blocks with different contents? Or similarly identical ones. You might consider reframing the task via an example using a smaller block size to give an idea of the intended meaning. Also, fix the indentation on the code, as it is now, anyone trying to help you will need to spend a lot of extra time parsing what the code does because the lack of indentation does not help at all.

Comment: When comparing the files, you read both fp1 and fp2 into block2. Then you compare  the last block from the first read of fp1 with the the current block of fp2. You also compare all 1024 bytes the whole of the last blocks, even though they are most likely shorter. Generally, actual blocks are 4096 and reading each block in 4 sections is sub-optimal. You could read full blocks and still do comparison in 1024-byte chunks. You can just fseek (SEEK_END) to find the file lengths, and do the math to find the total number of blocks. You really do not need to read the whole files first for that.

Comment: You also do not even check that the files were successfully opened.

Comment: Looks like you and [this poster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67246904/62576) are in the same class, as you've both asked almost identical questions at almost the same time. Perhaps you should work together.

Comment: you need to merge the accounts [Is there a way to combine or merge Stack Exchange accounts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336512/995714), https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts